# Creating Custom category Attribute - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to find a way to set a custom attribute to my categories so I can use that to show Grid/List mode.

I thought to use a Boolean field: "Force Grid mode: Yes/No" because per default all my categories is in List Mode, however, some specific categories I would like to show grid.

Then I can use that to set the mode in my list.phtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this thing ,you need to do two things.

### Create attribute:

First,create **a custom module** which *will create a category attribute using* **an installer**.

**Create module:**

**Step1** ,Create module registration file registration.php at *app\code\VendorName\ModuleName*. Code is below:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendorName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step2,** create module main config module.xml file at *`app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\etc`*. Code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step3:** Now you need to create an installer which will create so,goto

*`app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\SetUp\InstallData.php`*  and it code should be

```
<?php


namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'force_grid_mode',
            [
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'label' => 'Force Grid mod',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 30,
                        'group' => 'Display Settings',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

### Force Grid mode:

Second, rewrite the class **Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php**.bcoz in this class,at function `getCurrentMode()` magento set mode

Now create **di.xml** where you define configuration that which *class will rewrite and which class rewriting and di.xml* located at `app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\etc` and code is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" 
        type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
</config>
```

**Rewrite class code is:**

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product\ProductList;
class Toolbar extends Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar{

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreCategoryRegistry = null;

 public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
        ToolbarModel $toolbarModel,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        ProductList $productListHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
         \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
         $this->_coreCategoryRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $catalogSession ,$catalogConfig,$toolbarModel,
            $urlEncoder ,$productListHelper, $postDataHelper,$data );
    }

    public function getCurrentMode()
    {
        $mode = $this->_getData('_current_grid_mode');

        if ($mode) {

            if($this->_coreCategoryRegistry):
                if($this->_coreCategoryRegistry->getForceGridMode()==1):
                    return 'grid';
                endif;
            endif;

            return $mode;
        }
        $defaultMode = $this->_productListHelper->getDefaultViewMode($this->getModes());
        $mode = $this->_toolbarModel->getMode();
        if (!$mode || !isset($this->_availableMode[$mode])) {
            $mode = $defaultMode;
        }
        $this->setData('_current_grid_mode', $mode);
        if($this->_coreCategoryRegistry):
            if($this->_coreCategoryRegistry->getForceGridMode()==1):
                $this->setData('_current_grid_mode', 'grid');
            endif;
        endif;
        return $mode;
    }



}
```

**NOte that:code is not tested**

Comment: WOW. Thanks man. It partially worked. I did all, but I needed to stop on Step 3, which shows in my back-end the option to choose, but when I try to make work the Force Grid part my site just keep blank. So I'm wondering if there is an easy way to get that attribute value in my phtml because there I can easily switch between them.

Comment: Also on Step 3 " $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY" is missing a comma.

Comment: Do you know how to show this new attribute in my list.phtml ?

Comment: at `if($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()):
$this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getForceGridMode();
endif;`

Comment: I'm afraid It doesn't print nothing. I tried changing a little bit but print nothing: 
if($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()) {
 echo $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getForceGridMode(); 
}

Comment: Please, apologize my stupidity. Worked fine, it's just because when the answer is No it shows nothing, and only shows 1 when the answer is Yes.